# How should (currency) tags be defined?

Tags: discussion, tags

I haven't looked too much at the tags in use, but noticed an inconsistency in the currency tags for [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pay-a-student-loan-in-the-us-from-the-uk) -- 'usd' and 'british-pound'. I thought I'd create a meta question to discuss.

Comment: in addition to what Robert mentioned, you can also flag for moderator attention and we'll have a look!

Answer (score 3):

Did one of the other stack exchanges use both the abbreviation and the name as the tag like this:

[usd-us-dollar](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usd-us-dollar),  [gbp-british-pound](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gbp-british-pound), etc.

Comment: +1.  Those have the advantage of being keyword rich.  There might be a length limitation on some obscure ones, but the major ones all probably fit.

Comment: I just established a new tag 'cad-canadian-dollar' here:  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/where-can-i-open-a-bank-account-in-canadian-dollars-in-the-us ... we should change the other currency tags over time to match.

Comment: I've changed USD and GBP to the new style tag, and added a couple of more synonyms (noticed you had at least a couple there already.)

Comment: Just added eur-euro and a synonym from euro to eur-euro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tags have already been edited. What are your suggested changes?

Any user with 200+ reputation can edit tags. Since you do not yet have sufficient reputation, you can make your requests here (as you did) or comment on the individual posts.

Comment: He can also flag for moderator attention with only 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

Currencies have standard names (usd, gbp, etc.) so maybe standardize on them and alias other names ("us-dollar", "british-pound", "uk-pound") to them?